# Нужна ли запятая пред "если"?

Tags: пунктуация

"В случае(,) если режимы работы предприятия будут являться не характерными на 20 июня 2012г., прошу Вас предоставить указанные выше контрольные почасовые измерения  и за характерные сутки".

Answer (score 1):

Предложение сложное, сложноподчиненное, придаточная часть стоит в начале предложения и присоединяется составным союзов *в случае если* - запятая не нужна. 
Другое дело, если Вы добавите местоимение - в том случае, если...Получается уже придаточная часть внутри главной, присоединяется союзом если.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая версия: если это "В случае() если...то,..", то здесь запятая не нужна. Если же без "то", то запятую ставим.